# Trigger Promise when an event fires

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

My entire project uses (Bluebird) Promises, but there's one particular library that uses EventEmitter.

I want to achieve something like:

```
Promise.on('connect', function() {
    x.doSomething();
}).then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        y.doAction(resolve); // this will result in `eventB` getting emitted
    });
}).on('eventB', function() {
    z.handleEventB();
}).then(function() {
    z.doSomethingElse();
});
```

I read the answer to [EventEmitter in the middle of a chain of Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229057/1115059).
That gives me a way to execute the callback for 'connect' event.
Here's where I have got so far

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    emitter.on('connect', resolve);
});
p.on = function() {
    emitter.on.apply(emitter, arguments);
    return p;
};
p.on('connect', function() {
    x.doSomething();
}).then(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        y.doAction(resolve); // this will result in eventB getting emitted
    });
});
```

Now how to chain further for 'eventB' ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/promisify-event-emitter.html

Comment: cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20160320100756/http://bahmutov.calepin.co/promisify-event-emitter.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I assume you want to do a different chain of things for each event. Even if `eventB` is triggered by the actions of `connect`, you can treat it like another stream of logic.

*Side note: To avoid confusion for you and anyone else who has to read this codebase, I'd recommend against supplementing promises with additional methods unless you are **very** thorough about documenting them.*

From your example, it seems like the following would work.

```
var Promise = require( 'bluebird' )
var emitter = someEmitter()
var connected = new Promise( function( resolve ){
    emitter.on( 'connect', resolve )
})

var eventBHappened = new Promise( function( resolve ){
    emitter.on( 'eventB', resolve )
})

connected.then( function(){
    return x.doSomething()
}).then( function(){
    return y.doSomethingElse() // will trigger `eventB` eventually
})

// this promise stream will begin once `eventB` has been triggered
eventBHappened.then( function(){ 
    return z.doSomething()
})
```

If you'd like to simplify this constant

```
var p = new Promise( function( resolve ){
    emitter.on( 'something', resolve )
})
```

You can use something like this

```
function waitForEvent( emitter, eventType ){
    return new Promise( function( resolve ){
        emitter.on( eventType, resolve )
    })
}
```

Which turns the code solution above into

```
var Promise = require( 'bluebird' )
var emitter = someEmitter()

function waitForEvent( eventEmitter, eventType ){
    return new Promise( function( resolve ){
        eventEmitter.on( eventType, resolve )
    })
}

waitForEvent( emitter, 'connect' ).then( function(){
    return x.doSomething()
}).then( function(){
    return y.doSomethingElse() // will trigger `eventB` eventually
})

// this promise stream will begin once `eventB` has been triggered
waitForEvent( emitter, 'eventB' ).then( function(){ 
    return z.doSomething()
})
```

And because functions in Javascript capture the scope where they were defined, this code could be further simplified to

```
var Promise = require( 'bluebird' )
var emitter = someEmitter()

function waitForEvent( type ){
    return new Promise( function( resolve ){
        //emitter has been captured from line #2
        emitter.on( type, resolve ) 
    })
}

waitForEvent( 'connect' ).then( function(){
    return x.doSomething()
}).then( function(){
    return y.doSomethingElse() // will trigger `eventB` eventually
})

// this promise stream will begin once `eventB` has been triggered
waitForEvent( 'eventB' ).then( function(){ 
    return z.doSomething()
})
```

Comment: Can't promises only be resolved once? I don't think this would work for multi-event APIs.

Comment: @Grimtech you're right. If you need to listen to an event multiple times, they're not the right tool

Comment: use `.once` instead of `.on`, that way if an event is fired more than once, it won't break your promise (of course, use with care)

Comment: You can call `resolve()` inside a promise multiple times, but `.once` is still a good idea, since whatever is awaiting the Promise's resolution will only ever get the first value it resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem and wrote a tiny promise-wrapping library ([controlled-promise](https://github.com/vitalets/controlled-promise)) that allows to promisify event emitters. The solution for your example is:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const ControlledPromise = require('controlled-promise');

const emitter = someEmitter();
const waiting = new ControlledPromise();

function waitForEvent(type) {
    return waiting.call(() => {
       emitter.once(type, event => waiting.resolve(event));
    });
}

waitForEvent('connect')
    .then(() => x.doSomething())
    .then(() => waitForEvent('eventB'))
    .then(() => z.doSomethingElse());
```

The benefits of such approach:

- automatic return of existing promise while it is pending
- easy access to `resolve()` / `reject()` callbacks