# promise-based version of net.createServer

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

If I create TCP server with `net.createServer`, I can do `conn.on('data' ...)` in the connection handler with a callback. Is there version of this that return `Promise` so can be used with `async/await`? Or should I use some third-party library for this or roll my own wrapper for `conn.on('data' ...)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger Promise when an event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933088/trigger-promise-when-an-event-fires)

Comment: `await` does not make much sense in the context of TCP sockets. What are you awaiting? A single message? An then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`conn.on('data' ...)` can't be replaced with a promise, because it's an event listener, which means that the callback function can be called multiple times. A promise can't be resolved multiple times.

If you're sure that the `data` event will be emitted only once, you can write a wrapper which will return a promise:

```
const onData = conn =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    conn.on('data', resolve);
    conn.on('error', reject);
  });
```