# Resolve *and* reject all promises in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm looking for the way to get both resolutions and rejections from promise array. I'm currently counting on Bluebird implementation, so ES6 compatible solution would be suitable, too.

The best thing that comes to mind is to use Bluebird's `Promise.settle` for that, and I consider promise inspections an unnecessary complication here:

```
  let promises = [
    Promise.resolve('resolved'),
    Promise.resolve('resolved'),
    Promise.reject('rejected')
  ];

  // is there an existing way to do this?
  let resolvedAndRejected = Promise.settle(promises)
  .then((inspections) => {
    let resolved = [];
    let rejected = [];

    inspections.forEach((inspection) => {
      if (inspection.isFulfilled())
        resolved.push(inspection.value());
      else if (inspection.isRejected())
        rejected.push(inspection.reason());
    });

    return [resolved, rejected];
  });

  resolvedAndRejected.spread((resolved, rejected) => {
    console.log(...resolved);
    console.error(...rejected);
  });
```

It looks like a trivial task for the cases where 100% fulfillment rate isn't an option or a goal, but I don't even know the name for the recipe.

Is there a neat and well-proven way to handle this in Bluebird or other promise implementations - built-in operator or extension?

Comment: You can use `Promise.all()`, handle rejected promises, return `reason` to chained `.then()`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042068/why-is-onrejected-not-called-following-promise-all-where-promise-reject-incl; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131082/jquery-ajax-prevent-fail-in-a-deferred-sequential-loop/

Comment: @guest271314 I see difficulties with distinguishing caught rejections from resolutions in this case. I believe that the first question considers some different scenario. Your answer on `$.when.all` looks very similar, but I cannot imagine how $ deferreds could be translated to A+ promises in this case - deferreds expose their state, while promises don't.

Comment: The approach is to handle rejected promise. Once a rejected promise is handled, the `reason` or value can be returned to chained `.then()`, where the value would then be a resolved promise, then store both resolved, rejected promises to an array or other object.  Note the `.then()` within `.map()` at first link, where rejected promise is handled. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630870/conditional-on-promise-all/, and this poorly cobbled together Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688342/how-to-return-accumulated-returned-promise-values-as-array-to-then-following

Comment: What are you going to with the list of resolved and rejected promises once you get it?

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, I think I've got the idea. Feel free to submit the answer if you will come up with something.

Comment: @torazaburo I've stumbled upon the same pattern several times. My current case is http request queue, depending on the settings and success/fail ratio rejected requests may be re-added to the queue or ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added answer for completeness since OP asked. Here is what I'd do:

```
 const res = Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.reflect())) // get promises
   .then(values => [
          values.filter(x => x.isFulfilled()).map(x => x.value()), // resolved
          values.filter(x => x.isRejected()).map(x => x.reason()) // rejected
   ]);
```

Comment: This may be `Promise.all(promises.map(p => Promise.resolve(p).reflect()))...` to support non-Bluebird promises, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built in for it, but `reduce` can make it pretty succinct:

```
Promise
  .settle(promises)
  .reduce(([resolved, rejected], inspection) => {
    if (inspection.isFulfilled())
      resolved.push(inspection.value());
    else
      rejected.push(inspection.reason());
    return [resolved, rejected];
  }, [[], []]);
```

Comment: Very neat indeed, thanks! I believe `isRejected()` is there [for a *reason*](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reason.html). Not sure if settled promise can become 'pending', but it can certainly be 'cancelled'.

Comment: I thought `settle` was deprecated.

Comment: Seems to be; can replace that part with `Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.reflect()))`

Comment: Settle is deprecated and your change suggestion is good, please implemented :)

Comment: `promises.map(p => p.reflect()).all().then(values => [values.filter(x => x.isFulfilled()).map(x => x.value()), values.filter(x => x.isRejected()).map(x => x.reason())])` basically.

Comment: FWIW, I use `bluebird-settle` to forwardport a deprecated method. Nice one, @BenjaminGruenbaum! You could submit this as an answer for visibility. There's a typo, I guess this should be `Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.reflect()))`.

Comment: @estus I deprecated settle, so if you're going to port it since you find it useful - I want to know why. I'll add an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. Never used it in real life until now - as well as 51% of BB API. But `settle` is/was a documented method with expected outcome, which is important for established API. In my particular case (the question wasn't supposed to reflect this) `promises` are native Promises, so they should be BB-ified first to be mapped to `reflect`. I guess this won't be a problem for `Bluebird.settle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all()`, handle rejected `Promise`, `return` `reason` or other value to chained `.then()`

```js
let promises = [
  Promise.resolve("resolved"),
  Promise.resolve("resolved"),
  Promise.reject("rejected")
]
, results = {resolved:[], rejected:[]}

, resolvedAndRejected = Promise.all(
  promises.map((p) => {
    return p.then((resolvedValue) => {
      results.resolved.push(resolvedValue);
      return resolvedValue
    }, (rejectedReason) => {
      results.rejected.push(rejectedReason);
      return rejectedReason
    })
  }));

resolvedAndRejected.then((data) => {
  console.log(data, results)
});
```