# Mongoose doesn't find last created entries until I refresh page

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this

```
router.get('/documents', function(req, res, next) {
  Document.find(function(err, doc){
    res.render('documents', { doc: doc });
  });
});

router.post('/documents', function(req, res, next) {
  // Create function
  req.body.newdocs.forEach(function(newdoc) {
    Document.create({title : newdoc.title, desc: newdoc.desc}, function (err, ndoc) {
      if (err) {
        res.flash('error', "Error. Try again.");
        res.redirect('/documents');
      }
    });
  });      

  // Update function
  req.body.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
    var d = {
      title: doc.title,
      desc: doc.desc
    }
    Document.update({'_id': doc.id}, d, {overwrite: true}, function(err, raw) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/documents');
});
```

When I create some documents, post them (documents are created in database) and the redirection works. So I get the page, but I only **have the documents before the post**. And when I refresh the page (GET the page one more time), I have well the new documents.

Do you have some ideas of explanation, to fix this ?

Comment: Could you just resissue the request without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you dont wait for the update function to complete. :)
You tell the database to save the documents with:

```
Document.update({'_id': doc.id}, d, {overwrite: true}...
```

But mongo does updates async, which means that this code will just query them and continue, without waiting for the **actual update**. For your code to be proper, you need to run `res.redirect('/documents');` in the callback (which is the function that gets executed **after** the actual update is done).
So your code should look like this:

```
Document.update({'_id': doc.id}, d, {overwrite: true}, function(err, raw) {
   if (err) return handleError(err);
   res.redirect('/documents');
});
```

Promise.all example, as requested by @XavierB

```
//Push all of the promises into one array
let promises = [];
promises.push(Document.update({'_id': doc.id}, d, {overwrite: true}));
//Await for all of the promises to be done
Promises.all(promises).then(function(){
    //All of the promises were resolved
    res.redirect('/documents');
}).catch(err => { 
    //Something went terribly wrong with ANY of the promises.
    console.log(err); 
});;
```

Comment: The original code performs multiple DB queries within a pair of loops. It might be better to use `Promise.all` to wait for them all rather than trying to juggle the callbacks.

Comment: Youre right, my answer was just a simplified version, focusing on explaining why code doesnt work. :) If he wants to replace both .each loops, then yes, Promise.all is the way to go.

Comment: Can you be more precise. How can I use `Promise.all` ? I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362231/how-to-use-promise-in-foreach-loop-of-array-to-populate-an-object) but don't know exactly how to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is async, it takes for a while to finish. You should use async await or .then to run the res.redirect('/') in the callback, it will work as you expect