# Sequelize: Retrieve all descendants of an id with a recursive function

Tags: node.js, recursion, sequelize.js

I'm using `Sequelize` for one project and have already created a Category table, where I store all of my categories in a **parent-child** relationship. I do know about the package `sequelize-hierarchy`, but I wanted to try to find all descendants with a recursive function. So when a receive the categoryId from the client side, I check if it has any children.

```
const categoryChildren = await db.Category.findAll({attributes:['id'], where: {parent_id: categoryId}});
```

If it has, then I call a function `getDescendants` which has the following declaration:

```
async function getDescendants (children, storage) {
    await children.forEach(async (elem) => {
        const hasChildren = await db.category.findAll({attributes:['id'], where:{'parent_id': elem }});
        if (hasChildren.length !== 0) {
            let ids = [];
            hasChildren.forEach( child => {    //Transform the response in an array of the elements ID's
                ids = [...ids, child.id];
            });
            storage = [...storage,elem];
            return getDescendants(ids, storage);          
        } else {
            storage = [...storage,elem];
            return storage;
        }
        //console.log(storage); //After adding return to getDescendants(ids, storage) this won't run
    });
    return storage;
}
```

And I use await because the process will take a while:

```
const descendants = await getDescendants(children, []);
```

The `console.log` call in my function gets executed and I see my correct ID's after each iteration. However, I receive always an empty array as a result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you are missing `return` in front of `getDescendants(ids, storage)` at the recursion.

Comment: I've tried with it and there is no change

Comment: Could you update your code?  also I think `hasChildren` can never been falsely value.  `findAll` returns array and in case of no children it will be empty array.  `if([])` is true.  This still doesn't explain why it is not working though.

Comment: I've updated it and there is still no change. (have forgot that an empty array is also true...)

Comment: Async/Await can only work on functions that return a Promise, so you have to wrap your `getDecendants` function in Promise.  However, it is still complicated with when to `resolve` because you have `async/await` within `forEach`.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362312/2956135

Comment: Thanks. It's only for the test. The library which the ```Sequelize``` team provides is good and can resolve the problem. Just wanted to test whether I can simplify the problem.

Comment: You are using `async/await` which not works on `foreach` (you can search web, why it not works). Instead, please use `for` loop.

Comment: hi, did you managed to solve this?