# Method returns a null

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

For some reason my `listImage()` method returns a null I don't know what I could be doing wrong. for some reason my `listImage()` method returns `null`.

```js
import {
  Injectable,
}
from '@angular/core'
declare
var firebase;

@
Injectable()
export class StorageService {

  img:any;

  listImage() {

    var getImages = firebase.database().ref('flats').once('value');
    getImages.then(snapshot => {
      var imgName = snapshot.val();
      var names;

      snapshot.forEach(imgName => {
        names = imgName.val();
        let i = names.image;
        //console.log(i);
        let key = imgName.key
        firebase.storage().ref(i + '.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(url => {
          this.img = url;
        });
      })
    })
    return this.img;
  }

}
```

could it be the `forEach()` restricting it

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, service: StorageService) {
  this.service = service;
  var img = this.service.listImage();
  console.log(img); //this returns null what could be the issue?
}
```

Comment: It's asynchronous method.There are a lot of question related with this problem. I thing it's non angular2 issue

Comment: oh i see isn't there an angular method or library that can workaround this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JS is asynchronous. It has nothing to do with Angular 2 itself.

When you call the `listenImage()` function you are using a promise which is the correct way to handle this.
But look at your return command:
`return this.img;`

It is not handled inside the promise, since it is not inside any `.then()`
So you basically call your `getImages()` promise and jump to the return command without waiting for any results.

In addition to that, you are making asynchronous calls inside the foreach which is not asynchronous.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413749/node-js-promise-all-and-foreach) is a good answer that describes how you should correctly work with promises during asynchronous tasks.
And you should also definitely have a look at [this](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) to see how you should deal with the foreach and other loops when working with promises (it's under Rookie Mistakes #2).

Comment: yeah, read `$q` documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q