# Using Promise.all on my db.collection forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, node-mongodb-native

How can I use promise.all with this function :

```
function getUsersGroups(users, req) {
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    user.groups = [];

    db.collection("groups")
      .find({ "users._id": String(user._id) })
      .toArray(function(err, docs) {
          user.groups = docs;
      });
  });

  return users;
}
```

I don't know how to do , thank you.

PS : the users array doesn't get actualized with the docs (they console log ok).

Thi is my second try :

```
function getUsersGroups(users, req) {
  users.forEach(
    (user, index, array) => (
      array[index].user =[]
      array[index].user.groups = myApiCall(user))
  );

  function myApiCall(user) {
    db.collection("groups")
      .find({ "users._id": String(user._id) })
      .toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        return docs;
      });
  }

  return users;
}



  array[index].user.groups = myApiCall(user))
      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

**Edit :**

So finally, I'm using this function, like Ashish said ( it is getting all of the groups a user is in, and updating the users model) :

```
async function getUsersGroups(users, req) {
  await Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    return db.collection("groups")
      .find({ "users._id": String(user._id) })
      .toArray()
      .then(group => {
        user.groups = group;
      })
  }));

  return users;
}
```

And I am calling like this inside of another node.js function :

```
 getUsersGroups(docs, req)
          .then(users => {
            res.send(users);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // if you have an error
          });
```

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Is this related to `node-mongodb-native`?

Comment: yes there are multiple api calls .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Promise.all and forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413749/node-js-promise-all-and-foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getUsersGroups(users, req) {
  await Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    return db.collection("groups")
      .find({ "users._id": String(user._id) })
      .toArray()
      .then(group => {
        user.groups = group;
      })
  }));

  return users;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, how do I return users ? i'm calling the function like this : docs = getUsersGroups(docs, req);

Comment: @harmoniuscool I have edited my answer.basically await the promise all to let it complete and then return user.

Comment: How do I call this function ?

Comment: await Promise.all(users.map(user => {
  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: just need to ass `async` for the function getUsersGroups. I have added that.

Comment: @harmoniuscool you can return `users`. it was a typo. corrected that.

Comment: Do I have to call it like this : getUsersGroups(docs, req)
          .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // if you have an error
          });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205468/discussion-between-ashish-modi-and-harmonius-cool).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for `toArray`, it returns a `Promise` if the callback is not specified. We can then use `.map` instead of `.forEach` to produce an array of promises, which we can then pass to `Promise.all`:

```
function getUsersGroups(users, req) {
  const promises = users.map(function(user) {
    user.groups = []
    return db
      .collection("groups")
      .find({ "users._id": String(user._id) })
      .toArray()
      .then(groups => {
        user.groups = groups
      })
  });

  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Notice that this mutates the user objects. That is, whatever `users` you pass in to the function will be modified with the `groups` field getting set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your function is working, but when I'm calling it from another function, getUsersGroups(docs, req); is empty, while console.log(groups) says it is populated when inside of getUsersGroups().

Comment: How do I call this function ?

Comment: I'm trying to call it like this : getUsersGroups(docs, req)
          .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.send(result);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // if you have an error
          }); with no luck

Comment: Thank you a lot for your excellent answer , I've finally used the Ashish answer , and called the function like this  getUsersGroups(docs, req) .then(result => { console.log(result); res.send(result); }) .catch(error => { // if you have an error });  but I guess that your answer is also working .